# Pass id in Videos Slideshow in Angular 12

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have created a video slideshow in my Ionic 5 Angular 12 project. I have also created a play/pause button so that the user may play or pause each video. But everytime i tap in one video, all videos play not only one. I guess i need to pass the id of the video to the .ts play/pause function, right? Or is there any other way?

html. media are the video (object) parameters like id, name etc...

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let media of medias | filterByType: mediaType; let i = index">
<ng-container>
<div class="container" (click)="playVideo()">
    <video autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"
       onloadedmetadata="this.muted=true" class="fillWidth" preload="metadata" 
       #video>
        <source [src]="media?.image_path" [type]="'video/webm'">
        <source [src]="media?.image_path" [type]="'video/mp4'">
        <source [src]="media?.image_path" [type]="'video/ogg'">
    </video>
 </div>
 </ng-container>
 </ion-slide>
```

.ts

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('video') myVideo: ElementRef;

  isplay = false;


 playVideo(){
    if(this.isplay){
        this.myVideo.nativeElement.pause();
    }
    else{
        this.myVideo.nativeElement.play();
    }  
    this.isplay=!this.isplay
  }
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use js code in your project and access DOM directly (remember to use it with caution). Try something like:

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let media of medias | filterByType: mediaType; let i = index">
<ng-container>
<div class="container" (click)="playVideo('video'+i)">
    <video autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"
       onloadedmetadata="this.muted=true" class="fillWidth" preload="metadata" 
       [id]="'video'+i">
        <source [src]="media?.image_path" [type]="'video/webm'">
        <source [src]="media?.image_path" [type]="'video/mp4'">
        <source [src]="media?.image_path" [type]="'video/ogg'">
    </video>
 </div>
 </ng-container>
 </ion-slide>
```

.ts:

```
 playVideo(id: string){
        if(this.isplay){
            (document.getElementById(id) as HTMLMediaElement).pause();
        }
        else{
            (document.getElementById(id) as HTMLMediaElement).play();
        }  
        this.isplay=!this.isplay
      }
```

You have many elements so probably you need to store isplay for each one of them, or pause the previous video before playing new one.

Comment: Yes a good thought but as you said you have to use it with caution. I am getting 'Property play doesn't not exist on HTMLElement'

Comment: and id (id:HTMLElement) i am getting Argument of type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)

Comment: It was more like a concept. I updated answer to fix first comment. I don't know which line the second error refers to.

Comment: Sorry Drazu can you see this one too? its for custom players https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74565766/angular-12-pass-index-number-for-custom-audio-player